# When should I use "is","does" and "has"?

Tags: questions

I called one shop to ask whether the shop was open or not.

Which sentence should I have used?

- Is the shop opened?
- Does the shop opened?
- Has the shop opened?

Comment: In the first line, "find out" is better than "know", as it implies that you're aiming to discover some information.

Comment: "Is the shop opened?" and "Has the shop opened?" are both grammatically correct.  If you are calling a shop on the phone, it would probably be most natural to say "Are you open," "When are you open," or "What are your hours?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should ask is:

- Is the shop open?
- When does the shop open?
- What are the shop's opening hours?

In the first sentence, *open* is used as adjective.
The second and third sentence are not simply asking if the shop is open, but when the shop will be open.

"Does the shop opened?" is not grammatically correct, and you don't normally use the present perfect to ask if a shop is already open.

Comment: "When are the shop's opening hours?" would be preferable, since the plural "hours" is what is being asked about.

Comment: Whoops... I started writing something else, and then changed sentence.

Comment: @barbarabeeton really?  I can't imagine anyone ever saying "When are the shops opening hours?"  It sounds overly formal.  In fact, the phrase, "opening hours," just sounds ridiculous to me.  That's not to say nobody uses it; I've just never heard it.  If it were me, I'd call and ask "When are you open?" or "What are your hours?"

Comment: @YesIuseMUMPS -- Oops!  I really meant "What ...", simply to comment on the verb being used in the third example of the answer.  I agree it sounds formal, and "What are your hours?" is more natural.